# How can I make my ASP.NET Core website with Blazor webassembly load faster?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I created a website [enter link description here](https://bluecodes.azurewebsites.net/) in ASP.NET Core with Blazor webassembly, but loading and authentication is taking about 7 seconds to finish.

Can anyone tell me how I can make the website faster?

Comment: Is that 7 seconds in Develop mode or after it's Published ?

Comment: It is already published: https://bluecodes.co/

Comment: OK, open the Dev Tools in your browser and do a refresh. Which request takes up most time?

Comment: This could be a ton of issues and usually the front-end lets say shouldnt be the first. Have you validated that this time is not due to your backend or your authentication mechanism? I would start looking at the backend making sure that the database and API are performant and then look at the front end. It's also a matter of where they are published. Check everything in local host to see the actual computational cost.

Comment: 6 of the elements that take most of the time, are images. I can make those abit smaller, but my issue is also the authentication before loading the contents.